# Why it still complains about libcurl.so.4?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, gcc, cmake

I ln ing the curl from /usr/bin/curl to /usr/local/bin/curl.
  When I run from command line, the "no version information available" is gone, but when I compile it in home environment, it still complains about it:
   cmake: ~/local/lib/libcurl.so.4: no version information available (required by cmake) /bin/bash: line 14: 63003 Segmentation fault.

When I look at the local version:
./curl --version
curl 7.27.0-DEV (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.27.0-DEV OpenSSL/1.0.1f zlib/1.2.8 libssh2/1.4.0_DEV
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP

It was installed via apt-get libcurl4-openssl-dev, couldn't remove it.

How do I install it in local/bin and local/lib?

Thanks

Comment: what are you asking? could you post some of your cmake linking lib curl? `~/local/...` leads me to believe it's not looking in the right place for libcurl

Comment: I've a curl in /usr/bin/curl, I linked it to my local curl, it's fine on command line, but not compile libraries, how curl find libcurl.so? I saw it on local/lib, the version is 
curl 7.27.0-DEV (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.27.0-DEV OpenSSL/1.0.1f zlib/1.2.8 libssh2/1.4.0_DEV @kirinthos

Comment: the binary most likely statically linked it's library, are you using Linux? perhaps Ubuntu? try [installing the curl dev packages](http://askubuntu.com/questions/78183/installing-curl-h-library) for your distro. if you are compiling curl yourself refer to the answer below

Comment: I am using ubuntu 14, the local curl comes with the project, should I reinstall it from source or on the system level? Was there a problem with the local version and the linked libcurl.so.4? How to check on the version thing with linked/dependent library? THANKS! @kirinthos

Comment: try this on the library see if it has any output, I'm unsure exactly how to check version embedded in curl `readelf -d  /path/to/libcurl.so.4 | grep -i curl`

Comment: I got these in local/lib:  0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libcurl.so.4]
 0x000000000000000e (SONAME)             Library soname: [libcurlpp.so.0]

How to reinstall/install the libcurl-dev with apt-get install libcurl4-gnutl-devs, it's not working I don't have aptitude. Was there a problem with the local version and the linked libcurl.so.4.22.0?THANKS! @kirinthos

Comment: well if it's their compiled version I'm unsure, you will need to get one with proper version codes, are you sure you're running Ubuntu? what does `uname -a` say

Answer (score 0):

You have a library compiled without version symbols.

The library has version symbols for very important purpose: asserting the library is modern enough to fit the requirements of the program. If cmake complains about the library, it means that:

1. You've compiled it without version symbols (probable)
2. You compiled too old version

Comment: Thanks, how to add version symbols and why cmake want libcurl since I compile to build a project that has many libraries.

Comment: I don't know. Use linker scripts or .symver assembly pseudo-op

Comment: When I do: dbkg  -s curl: Version: 7.35.0-1ubuntu2.5
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.17), libcurl3 (= 7.35.0-1ubuntu2.5), zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4), then I removed it, still got the same compile error, why the local lib curl's version is:curl 7.27.0-DEV (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.27.0-DEV OpenSSL/1.0.1f zlib/1.2.8 libssh2/1.4.0_DEV

Comment: So the local CURL may be too old. Your package may be requiring curl higher that 7.27, but lower/equal to 7.35. Also, the "-DEV" prefix means that the version is not a releasee, but a development status. It may be unstable.

Comment: **I meant to remove your curl and leave the system one**

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the name "libcurl.so.4".  I had a similar problem on Linux Mint 18 (base - Ubuntu 16.04), 64 bit, installing a new .deb file for software previously only available for Windoze.  The install was faultless but when I tried to run the programme, it failed with the message "error while loading shared libraries: libcurl.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory".

The supplier advised me to install "curl" but it was already there.  I fully uninstalled it then reinstalled without any change.  I then did a scan for "libcurl.so.4" on my hard disk without result.  The nearest I could find for it were in "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/".  The files were "libcurl-gnutls.so.3", "libcurl-gnutls.so.4" and "libcurl-gnutls.so.4.4.0".  The first two being symlinks to the third.  I then added a further symlink to "libcurl-gnutls.so.4.4.0" called "libcurl.so.4" and this allowed me to run the new version without problems.